# How to apply a regex just for a part of string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, substr

I have a string like this:

```
var str = "this is test
            1. this is test
            2. this is test
            3. this is test
            this is test
             1. this test   
             2. this is test
            this is test";
```

Also I have this regex:

```
/^[\s\S]*(?:^|\r?\n)\s*(\d+)(?![\s\S]*(\r?\n){2})/m
```

This capturing group [`$1` returns `2`](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/335) from above string.

Now I have a position number: `65` and I want to apply that regex in this range of the string: `[0 - 65]`. (So I have to get `3` instead of `2`). In general I want to limit that string from first to a specific position and then apply that regex on that range. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to apply it to just that substring:

```
var match = /^[\s\S]*(?:^|\r?\n)\s*(\d+)(?![\s\S]*(\r?\n){2})/m.exec(str.substring(0, 65));
// Note ----------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Example:

```js
var str = "this is test\n1. this is test\n2. this is test\n3. this is test\nthis is test\n1. this test   \n2. this is test\nthis is test";
var match = /^[\s\S]*(?:^|\r?\n)\s*(\d+)(?![\s\S]*(\r?\n){2})/m.exec(str.substring(0, 65));
    // Note ----------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

document.body.innerHTML = match ? "First capture: [" + match[1] + "]" : "(no match)";
```

Comment: Can you please tell me [how can I do that for `.replace()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35030402/how-to-replace-at-the-particular-range-of-indexes)?, Actually I need to do this `str.replace(/^(.*)$/gm, " $1");` just for this range `substring(0, 65)`. How can I do that?

Comment: @stack: `result = str.substring(0, 65).replace(/*...*/) + str.substring(65);`

Comment: Sorry to ask again, but in reality the range doesn't start from `0`, it is this: `[20 - 50]`. So do I need to add something to your code?

Comment: @stack: If you look at the pieces of the above, it should be fairly clear: `result = str.substring(0, 20) + str.substring(20, 50).replace(/*...*/) + str.substring(50);`

Comment: Yes I knew it, I just wanted to know what I did is standard approach or not,   and now I'm sure what I did is fine :-) !! Sorry I'm kinda obsession. Anyway thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe such a build can help (source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

```
var myRe = /ab*/g;
var str = 'abbcdefabh';
var myArray;
while ((myArray = myRe.exec(str)) !== null) {
  var msg = 'Found ' + myArray[0] + '. ';
  msg += 'Next match starts at ' + myRe.lastIndex;
  console.log(msg);
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this limits the match to the first 65 characters. It does a loop, which is fine, but doesn't limit to the first 65 characters.