# How to replace at the particular range of indexes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string like this:

```
var str = "this is test1
           this is test2
           this is test3
           this is test4";
```

Now I want to append 4 spaces before every lines which are between this range: `[14 - 40]`. So I want this **output**:

```
var str = "this is test1
               this is test2
               this is test3
           this is test4";
```

In other word, I want to apply this replace just for a specific range:

```
var output = str.replace(/^(.*)$/gm, "    $1");
```

But as you know, the above code replaces that regex for all of that string, Well, how can I limit it for just specific positions?

Comment: `Range 14-40`? are these like `test14 - test40` or are they index value.

Comment: @Rajesh No, they are just index value.

Comment: So should it not be an array instead?

Comment: slice+concat; left+mid.replace+right

Comment: @Rajesh There isn't any array, there is just a string and I want a string as output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `replace` with `callback`:

```
var str = "this is test1\n"+
           "this is test2\n"+
           "this is test3\n"+
           "this is test4";

var posStart = 14; // start index
var posEnd   = 40; // end index
var re = new RegExp(
  '^([\\s\\S]{' + (posStart-1) + '})([\\s\\S]{' + (posEnd-posStart+1) + '})');
//=> re = /^([\s\S]{13})([\s\S]{27})/

var r = str.replace(re, function($0, $1, $2) {
    return $1+$2.replace(/\n/g, '\n    '); });

console.log(r);
/* 
"this is test1
    this is test2
    this is test3
this is test4"
*/
```

Regex `^([\s\S]{13})([\s\S]{27})` makes sure replacement happens between position `14-40` only.

Comment: OP wrote: **I want to append 4 spaces**

Comment: Very good +1 .. thank you. But one thing, where do those number in your regex come from? (`13`, 27) I mean how do you calculate them?

Comment: That is due to your requirement of replacing only in position `14-40` in input. So `13` characters before target is `$1` and then `14-40` makes it next `27`

Comment: And my last question, how can I use variable instead of those number in the regex? (`13`, `27`)

Comment: Let me modify the answer accordingly for that

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

Also note, its not a good option to check for char index for logic.

```js
function addSpaces(){
  var str = "this is test1\n"+
            "this is test2\n"+
            "this is test3\n"+
            "this is test4"
  var data = str.split("\n");
  
  var result = data.map(function(item, index){
    if(index >0 && index < data.length-1){
      item = "    " + item;
    }
    return item;
  }).join("\n");
  
  console.log(result)
}

addSpaces();
```

Comment: `:-)` thank you.. But look, there is just 4 lines .. As you see in the example. I need to append 4 space *(or apply that regex)* just before second and third lines *(or this range `[14 - 40]`)*

Comment: @stack I'll delete my answer. But please explain your problem statement. Also by range do you mean char index?

Comment: Ok, please take a look at this: `t(0)h(1)i(2)s(3) (4)i(5)s(6) (7)t(8)e(9)s(10)t(11)1(12) ...`, see? every character has a number .. Now I want to apply that regex for this range: `[14 - 40]`, `14` and `40` are the numbers of position.

Comment: So to rephrase, for the range, `14-40`, after every new line character, you want to add 4 spaces. right?

Comment: @stack I have updated my answer per my understanding of question. Hope it helps